# Access FMU system variables during simulation

Tags: python, modelica, jmodelica

I have a FMU which I am attempting to simulate in JModelica. The `input` parameter needs to refer to the current state of some of the variables in the JModelica FMU simulation. However, I'm having trouble accessing these.

Reading the documentation, I would be given to believe that the functions `.get_variable_nominal()` or `.get()` would provide access to these, but this is not the case.

The basic structure of the code is as follows:

```py
from pyfmi import load_fmu
model = none

def inputFunction(t):
   global model
   # Get current state of desired variable(s)
   variable = model.some_function("object.variable_name")
   # Do some mathematical process to get input value
   input_value = foo(variable)
   return input_value

def main():
    global model
    # FMU's input variables
    inputs = ["list", "of", "input", "variables"]
    # Get model from FMU file
    model = load_fmu("model_name.fmu")
    # Create input object for simulation method
    inputObj = (inputs, inputFunction)

    # Do some simulation
    opts = model.simulate_options()
    results = model.simulate(start_time=0, final_time=100.0, input=inputObj, options=opts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If in the place of `.some_function("object.variable_name")`, I use `.get_variable_nominal("object.variable_name")`, the function returns a float value of `1.0` (I seem to get different arbitrary values if I specify a different FMU variable). Whereas with `.get("object.variable_name")`, the error `FMUException: Failed to get the Real values.` is returned. The value I am expecting at the beginning of the simulation is a `float` value of approximately `303`.

Note that the FMU simulation behaves correctly if run with fixed input values, so the correct values are indeed stored in the model.

Thank-you to anyone who can help me understand what is going on here.